# Calculating magnetic field of solenoid (displacement current)

Tags: electromagnetism

If I have an infinite cylinder with radius $R$ and a surface density of current that varies with time, I can use ampere's law to calculate the magnetic field. My question is why is possible to ignore the displacement current when calculating the magnetic field, in this case?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since my electromagnetism course but could it be by the symmetry of the problem? In an *infinte* cylinder with surface density $\vec{\sigma}=\sigma(t) \vec{e}_{\rho}$, the electric field $\vec{E}$ should be perpendicular to the outer surface of the cylinder i.e $\vec{E}\sim \vec{e}_{\rho}$ with $E_{\varphi}=E_{z}=0$ and the magnetic field goes parallel to the cylinder axis i.e $\vec{B}\sim \vec{e}_z$ with $B_{\varphi}=B_{\rho}=0$. Then if we suppose that $\vec{B}$ is homogeneous in the azimutal coordinate $\partial_\varphi B_z=0$ which makes totally sense you get $(\nabla \times \vec{B})_{\rho}=0$.